# Substituir um nome em todas as tabelas do banco de dados mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Bom dia.
Preciso substituir um dominio que esta em várias tabelas do BD. Seria essa a forma correta?

```
SELECT REPLACE('*', 'velho.dominio.com', 'novo.dominio.com');
```

Como são muitas tabelas quero que o select percorra tudo. Tabelas e linhas

Obrigado.

Comment: Acredito que isso não vá resolver. Não sei o quão grande é o seu banco de dados porém acredito que a melhor maneira seria dar um `dump` e em seguida `find` e `replace`. Veja se [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822638/find-and-replace-entire-mysql-database/4822691#4822691) não lhe ajuda.

Comment: Achei uma alternativa melhor... baixei o bd para o pc e depois usando notepad++ mudei tudo...rsrs

Comment: foi exatamente isso que o @8biT falou.

Comment: Não entendi pq não fazer um update? UPDATE _tabela_ set dominio = "novo.dominio.com" where dominio = "velho.dominio.com"